# How to load a HTML code with a Javascript in android's Webview

Tags: javascript, android, html, for-loop

I have a HTML code with the java Script given below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body style = "text-align:center">
<script>

var out = '';
for (var counter = 1; counter <= 10; counter++) 
    { 
        out += '<img src="http://shiaislamicbooks.com/books_snaps/UR335/'+counter+'.jpg"alt="Page No:'+counter+'" height="100%" width="100%" />';
    } 
document.write(out);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I just want to load this in my android's webview using the `loadDataWithBaseURL(null, htmlString ,"text/html", "UTF-8", null);` method

- In short all I need is that how can I convert the above HTML code(Having a java Script Loop) in the htmlString so that I can insert that in  `loadDataWithBaseURL(null, htmlString ,"text/html", "UTF-8", null);` method flexibly

Thanks

Comment: http://blog.tourizo.com/2009/02/how-to-display-local-file-in-android.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below snippet can help u ...

```
      webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
   webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
   //webView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");

   String customHtml = "<html><body><h1>Hello, WebView</h1></body></html>";
   webView.loadData(customHtml, "text/html", "UTF-8");
```

Comment: please convert my code which i have posted. I m not understanding how and where to place the double quotes ("") in my code please